# Datacenter staging area

Tags: dhcp, deployment

Does anyone has a good experience of setting a staging area in a remote data center?

Should it be on a separate VLAN, or it can run in same LAN, by tight control of which servers are allowed to boot from DHCP?

My idea in general is to allow something similar to our local staging area - but instead of bringing servers here, deploying then shipping to data center, they will be delivered directly to the data center and be deployed there.

Regards.

Comment: It would help if you explained what kind of services you want to run, why you want/need to use DHCP, and what sort of problems you foresee.

Comment: Hi.

We set-up small clusters of solutions, which start with couple of servers and grow as needed.

Today, as said, we prepare the servers in-house then ship them to data center.

What I look to do, is to establish the environment in the data center, which will involve DHCP / Kickstart.

Question is how to make it reliable enough, and prevent accidental deployment on production servers.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it without an extra vlan, but to protect your production environment, you should use an extra vlan just for the case.